# How do i use a hashing computed column after i have indexed a varchar(max) field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

I created a computed column of type varbinary and referenced a varchar(max) field.  Now, how do i use or invoke it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    computedcolumn
FROM
    table
```

For indexing, look for "computed columns" in the [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(SQL.90).aspx) statment. There are rules such as deterministic, and no longer than 900 bytes etc.

Is this what you wanted?